# django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

We have a Django project, which involves also IO operations with Postgres. 
Recently, we started getting from time to time the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

The error occur when trying to create an object:

```
SOME_MODEL_CLASS.objects.create(...)
```

I had many Postgres instances, but have not encountered such a problem.

My relevant Django project's database settings:

```
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
```

The Python's version is 3.6.9, and the package is:

```
    django==1.11.11
    psql==10
    psycopg2==2.7.7
```

I assume that version upgrade for one/some/all of Django, psql and psycopg2 might do the job, but understanding the reason will help to make sure (or increase the chance) that such an error won't happen again, or at least, will allow me to test it.

Any idea for the reason and for solution?

Comment: whats the full stacktrace

Comment: Were you able to find the cause?